# Roll one ellipse on another: Locus of center ever a circle?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, plane-curves

Let $E_1$ be an ellipse fixed in the plane.
Let $E_2$ be a second, possibly different ellipse, which rolls around
without slippage
outside $E_1$, touching perimeter-to-perimeter. Let $c_2(t)$ be the center of $E_2$
as a function of time $t$, where $t$ measures the progress of the rolling.

> ***Q***. Is the locus $c_2(t)$ ever an exact circle when
>   it is *not* the case that both $E_1$ and $E_2$ are circles?

---

[image: E1RollE2]

         

<sup>Image: Erik Mahieu [Mathematica Demo](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EllipseRollingAroundAnotherEllipse/).</sup>

---

It seems likely the answer is *No*, but perhaps one can cleverly "cancel out" two
eccentricities...

Comment: See [roulette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roulette_(curve)). Also [here](http://www.2dcurves.com/roulette/roulette.html).

Comment: @Lucian: Thanks for the links. Unless I am mistaken, they do not answer the question.

Comment: @Lucian: The curve in the question is not a roulette, because $c_2(t)$ is the _centre_ of $E_2$, not a point on its circumference.

Comment: @Tony, actually, nothing in the usual definition of a "roulette" says that the point should be on the circumference. Thus, both cycloids and trochoids are considered roulettes, to use the classical example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I presume the usual parametric equation $(a\cos t\quad b\sin t)^\top$ for the ellipse.)

In the general case of noncongruent ellipses, the incommensurate arclengths will certainly preclude a circular locus.

When the fixed and rolling ellipses are congruent, the locus of the center is the [pedal curve](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PedalCurve.html) of the ellipse with respect to its center, which is a quartic curve with the Cartesian equation, $(x^2 + y^2)^2 = 4 a^2 x^2 + 4 b^2 y^2$, and thus not a circle:

[image: elliptic lemniscate as a roulette]

The locus is called the "elliptic lemniscate", or the [lemniscate of Booth](http://mathcurve.com/courbes2d/booth/booth.shtml). (I am of course assuming that $a>b$; certainly, the center of a circle rolling on another circle will produce a circle!)

If you want to have a circle as a locus, then the tracing point should be the *focus* of the ellipse instead:

[image: I can't believe it's a circle!]

In particular, the circle thus generated is centered at $\left(-\sqrt{a^2 - b^2},0\right)$ and has a radius of $2a$.

(*Mathematica* code for generating the figures is available upon request.)

Comment: Bonus: the usual lemniscate of Bernoulli can be obtained as the trace of the center of an *equilateral hyperbola* rolling on a congruent hyperbola. (In fact, the Booth lemniscates in general are defined as the pedal curves of a central conic.)

Comment: Beautiful, J.M.!

Comment: Good thing I found this question, then. :)